# I have difficult understanding colon and semicolon use

Tags: swift

I am learning the basics in Swift and I don't understand the meaning of the colon and semicolon in Swift. Can someone explain easily? How to use them and meaning of them.

Comment: semicolon is like in every other language, is to end the statement , colon is use to declare the type, i think they are pretty straight forward, the thing you should be not understand should be others

Comment: You really should update your question with some examples you don't understand. But first, you really need to go through Apple's Swift language book. A question like this is far too basic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

**Semi-colon(;)** is used as the statement terminator. In swift it not mandatory to end the statement with a semi-colon. So you won't be needing semi-colon in swift.

**Colon(:)** is basically used to specify the type of any variable in swift. It is used in many other places as well like in dictionaries to separate key and value pair.

Comment: ternary operator, example (a == 100) print("hi") : print("bye") anyway neat clean answer +1

Answer (score 1):

**Semicolon** in swift can be used to terminate a statement but it is not required.

It is required only if you wish to write multiple statements in one line as in:

```
var x = 0; var y = "Example String" ; var z = 2.235;
```

**Colon** on the other hand is used to describe the type of the variable declared. Its called type-annotation.
for eg:

```
var x:Int = 0
```

Colon is usually not required as swift infers the type from the type of value assigned at the time of initialization only.

Comment: tanks allot, it is very clear to me  now

Comment: A colon can be used in far more places then just a variable's type.